# function calculation based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I am practising and new to create a function in Python with conditions:

**create a function that takes an input of an integer number (for example m, where m is between 2 to n, and n is the maximum number of rows)**. **This function calculates the ‘Sum A’ and ‘Sum B’ from the last m-days. There will be no value for the first m-days**

The original data:

```
V       TP         A                   B             Sum A   Sum B
3509    47.81               
4862    48.406667   235353.2133         
1810    49.26           89160.6         
3824    49.263333   188382.9867         
2209    47.386667                   104677.1467     
4558    45.573333                   207723.2533     
3832    44.396667                   170128.0267     
3778    43.75                          165287.5     
1005    44.64           44863.2         
4047    43.76                         177096.72     
2201    44.383333   97687.71667                     655447.7167 824912.6467
2507    45.156667   113207.7633                     533302.2667 824912.6467
4392    44.4333                        195151.2     444141.6667 1020063.847
3497    43.296667                   151408.4433       255758.68 1171472.29
1181    43.07                          50865.67       255758.68 1117660.813
1971    42.89                          84536.19       255758.68 994473.75
4994    43.563333   217555.2867                     473313.9667 824345.7233
2017    44.816667   90395.21667                     563709.1833 659058.2233
2823    44.936667     126856.21                     645702.1933 659058.2233
2774    45.13         125190.62                     770892.8133 481961.5033
```

Continue original data

```
Day
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
```

The attempt that I have done so far is and it shows error **KeyError 'A'**:

```
curret_period = int(input("enter days: "))
sumA = curret_period * ((df["A"] < df["A"]),'')
sumB = curret_period * ((df["B"] >= df["B"]),'')
print(sumA)
print(sumB)
```

I am wondering is there a better way to create the function? I also wonder if below is the one that I need?

```
def function_name()
    print()
```

Expected result when m= 10:

```
    A                     B                        Sum A       Sum B
0                                           
1   235353.21333333332                      
2    89160.59999999999                      
3   188382.98666666663                      
4                        104677.1466666667  
5                       207723.25333333333  
6                       170128.02666666667  
7                                 165287.5  
8   44863.200000000004                      
9                                177096.72  
10   97687.71666666666                          655447.7167    824912.6467
11  113207.76333333334                          533302.2667    824912.6467
12                                195151.2      444141.6667    1020063.847
13                       151408.4433333333        255758.68     1171472.29
14                       50865.66999999999        255758.68    1117660.813 
15                       84536.19000000002        255758.68      994473.75
16  217555.28666666665                          473313.9667    824345.7233
17   90395.21666666666                          563709.1833    659058.2233
18           126856.21                          645702.1933    659058.2233
19  125190.61999999998                          770892.8133    481961.5033
```

Any suggestion? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize `df.tail()` to get the last `m` rows of the dataframe and then simply `sum()` each column.

We can also check if `m` is not greater than the length of the dataframe, however even if you did not have this it would just `sum` the entire dataframe.

```
def sumof(df, m):
    if m <= len(df.index):
        rows = df.tail(m)
        print(rows['A'].sum())
        print(rows['B'].sum())
    else:
        print("'m' can not be greater than length of dataframe")
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your solution, however, it does not match my expected result and whenever I call the function to create the new column Sum A (I should've mention it on my questions, sorry), it always returns an error Value Error: Wrong number of items passed 9, placement implies 1. Based on my understanding its trying to fill in too much data? correct me if I am wrong

Comment: What are you calculating in your `sum()`? I do not understand how you're getting the numbers in the expected result.

Comment: Hi @PacketLoss, the expected result is based on the original data set that I am trying to recreat. And for the ```sum()``` based on my understanding is to sum the column ```A``` with condition m-days we enter when we call the function  ```sumMoneyFlow = sumof(df,10)```. The expected result is when ```m=10```.

Comment: Could you include the original data? I'm not going to be able to edit the answer to match what you want, as i cannot test it accurately.

Comment: Hi @PacketLoss, I have added the original data into my questions. To get A and B I used this line of code `df['A']= np.where(df['TP'].shift() < df['TP'],df['TP']*df['V'] , '')`. `df['B']= np.where(df['TP'].shift() >= df['TP'],df['TP']*df['V'] , '')`

Comment: So the premise is, when the function is called it returns ` sum()` of the last `x` rows with `x` provided with the call to the function?

Comment: Hi, @PacketLoss, yes that how it should work so when the function is called it returns the sum of A from the last row provided with the call to the function (in this case when m=10 should return my expected result). I have been playing it around again but no improvement..